# Series where the planet’s air is really polluted and there is a portal to take you to a world where the air is clean

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

The movie was released in the last 15 years, probably between 2008-2018.

"Pre-movie" (like what happens before the main part of the movie begins):

- The movie was in the future.
- The people have to wear gas masks to go outside because the air is so polluted.
- airpollution
- smog
- 2 child policy
- they had 3 kids
- the guy goes to prison
- There is some sort of transportation portal that brings some important people 85mio years in the past on another timeline
- The guy runs to the portal and gets there with his entire family

"Main movie" (most of the movie):

- The guy is on this new planet and I think he gets imprisoned.
- The people built a camp with walls because there are dinosaurs that can easily kill people.
- Then a few other things happen I don't clearly remember.
- I think there is also some sort of love story.
- Then the dinosaurs attack the camp and they have to defend it.

Comment: Sounds like Terra Nova; https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1641349/

Comment: Are the "animals" dinosaurs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **[Terra Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_(TV_series))**. Valorum gave the answer.

> The series is initially set in 2149, when overpopulation and declining air quality threaten all life on Earth. When scientists discover a temporal rift permitting (one-way) human transmission, they initiate a series of "pilgrimages" to a parallel "time stream" resembling Earth's Cretaceous Period.[5][6][7] The series focuses primarily on police officer James "Jim" Shannon, his wife Elisabeth, and their three children Josh, Maddy, and Zoe, as they join the colony there,[8][9] named "Terra Nova" (Latin for "New Earth" or "New World").
>
> Elisabeth Shannon is chosen to join Terra Nova for her medical expertise, and her two older children with her. Her husband, imprisoned for violating population control by harbouring a third child and assaulting an official agent to protect his young daughter, stows away to join them and eventually convinces the colony's leader, Commander Nathaniel Taylor, that his own police expertise is of use to the administration.
>
> Opposing the colony and its leader Taylor is a group of separatists known as the "Sixers", so called because they arrived in the "Sixth Pilgrimage", working in concert with corporate industrialists to strip the Cretaceous Earth of its resources and transmit them to 2149, allowing for massive profits at the cost of environmental destruction. It is later revealed that Commander Taylor's estranged grown son, Lucas, is working with the Sixers as well. Toward the end of the series, Lucas perfects travel to and from the future, thus enabling the industrialists, with a private army called "The Phoenix Group", to invade Terra Nova. At the end of the series, Jim Shannon returns to 2149 to destroy the gateway permitting travel to the Cretaceous, whereupon the Phoenix Group retreats to the nearby "Badlands", leaving behind a wooden ship's figurehead apparently located there by another temporal rift.