Movie where a family crosses through a dimensional portal and end up having to fight for power
Family crossed a portal. The father put his son in a bag to not leave him behind. When they crossed they got into a fight for power. It was a village. There were 2 groups.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! This is a bit light on detail at the moment, are there any extra details you could [edit] in? When did you watch this, for example? Was the portal discovered, or created through magic? What sort of clothes did the family wear, and was it any different to that of the villagers?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

This is Spielberg’s Terra Nova. The pilot was effectively a two part movie.

If you can identify it off of the listed details, I agree that it should be clear enough, if probably more than a bit sparse.

@DoscoJones the question’s open, go ahead and post that :)

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are a great opportunity to [edit] in newly realized details, e.g. "I know it can't be Parallel Worlds with the Palmers because there weren't pet velociraptors, the father was not obsessed with promotional Camel cigarette merchandise, and everyone in the other world practiced Escrima as a communal exercise activity."

This is very likely Spielberg’s Terra Nova. The pilot was effectively a two part movie.  If I'm right then this would be a duplicate of an earlier question.

The portal is both temporal and transdimensional.

The kid in the backpack was the family's illegal third child, a daughter.

Most of the travelers live in a protected village.

There is a power struggle between the formal leadership of the village and a group of exiles.



Said earlier question marked as a duplicate to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243518/series-where-the-planet-s-air-is-really-polluted-and-there-is-a-portal-to-take-y
